# Error passing parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [transactiondb] @dbname1 NVARCHAR(128)
AS
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(1000);
    SET @query = "SELECT TOP 10*
    FROM @dbname1.dbo.transaction";
    EXEC (@query);
GO
```

When I execute the stored procedure I get the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@dbname1"

I am pretty sure this is something to do with the way the variable is being passed, but I am really struggling to understand what is happening or how to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. it works for me,

```
Alter PROCEDURE [transactiondb] @dbname1 NVARCHAR(128)
AS
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(1000);
    SET @query = 'SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM ' +@dbname1+'.dbo.transaction';
    EXEC (@query);
Go
```